# MySQL: mixing SET @variable and SELECT in one statement

Tags: mysql

Lookin on SO I've found 3 different syntax to set variables but only the 3rd works. Can you explain why?

```
#doesn't work at all (error)
SET @N = 3; --3rd word
SET @delimiter = ' ';
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sentence`, @delimiter, @N), @delimiter, -1)
FROM
  `test`;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJXZQT7nQvAcbbfon4HRXr/1

```
#working not as expected
SELECT @N := 3;
SELECT @delimiter := ' ';
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sentence`, @delimiter, @N), @delimiter, -1)
FROM
  `test`;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJXZQT7nQvAcbbfon4HRXr/2

```
#working fine  
SELECT 3 INTO @N; 
SELECT ' ' INTO @delimiter;
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sentence`, @delimiter, @N), @delimiter, -1)
FROM
  `test`;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJXZQT7nQvAcbbfon4HRXr/3

Comment: Actually first query works fine in mysql you need to look a bit more carefully at dbfiddle BTW works fine in sqlfiddle too..

Comment: a extra trick is using CROSS JOIN to init the MySQL user vars in one go.. `... test
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT
      @N := 3
    , @delimiter := ' '
   ) AS init`

Comment: @RaymondNijland: very nice suggestion thanks to you

Comment: @P.Salmon: thanks also for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't test things with db-fiddle.com

In your first example the error is in your comment. To be a valid comment the `--` has to be followed by a whitespace.

When you fix that, all 3 work exactly the same on the official MySQL command line client! It still doesn't on db-fiddle.com, but like I said, that doesn't matter at all. Which one you choose is a matter of personal taste and if you want output on the command line or not. `SET` doesn't output, `SELECT` does.